# Was aged Ryan a CGI or it was different actor?

Tags: effects, saving-private-ryan

In the opening scene of *Saving Private Ryan*, when an old Ryan is at the cemetery, was this Matt Damon with makeup, CGI etc, or was it some other actor altogether?

Comment: Please [**follow the tour**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the cast list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saving_Private_Ryan#Cast) on Wikipedia, the elderly Private Ryan was played by a separate actor, Harrison Young.

Comment: Also according to IMDb (he's listed as "Ryan as Old Man"): https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120815/fullcredits

Comment: "elderly Private Ryan was played by a separate actor, Harrison Young" --- No pun indended :D